# Como fazer uma consulta em SQL que traz uma contagem de alguns resultados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Seguinte, estou desenvolvendo uma consulta em SQL e o objetivo dessa consulta é Contar os registros que atingiram o o valor abaixo de 99,7%(Como tenho os dados para isso já calculei e transformei em segundos) porém não está dando certo, e acaba retornado uma mensagem de erro no SQL Server.

Segue abaixo o código da QUERY

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN(
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN LEN([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL]) = 8 AND [INICIO] BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31 23:59:59'
                 THEN (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 1, 2) * 3600) 
            + (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 4, 2) * 60) + (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 7, 2)) 

                WHEN LEN([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL]) = 9 AND [INICIO] BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31 23:59:59' 
            THEN (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 1, 3) * 3600) 
            + (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 5, 2) * 60) + (SUBSTRING([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 8, 2)) 
        END)) < 366959808  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Total_Indisponibildiade_Inferior
 FROM [REPORT].[dbo].[report_sirea]
  WHERE [OPERADORA] = 'ALP' AND [GRUPO] = 'OPERADORA'
```

O erro que retorna é o seguinte

```
  Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
  Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an 
  aggregate or a subquery.
```

O que poderia ser feito para arrumar isso e ele só trazer na contagem aquilo que for menor que 366959808(Ou 99,7%)

Grato

Answer (score 0):

A causa do erro é que uma função de agregação (SUM) foi utilizada dentro de outra função de agregação (COUNT).

Avalie:

```
-- código #1 v3
;with Soma_Indisp as (
SELECT sum (case when len ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL]) = 8
                      then datediff (second, 0, cast ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL] as time(0)))
                 when len ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL]) = 9
                      then (cast (substring ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 1, 3) as int) * 3600) +
                           (cast (substring ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 5, 2) as int) * 60) +
                           (cast (substring ([TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 7, 2) as int) 
                 else (1/0) end
           ) as Somado
  from REPORT.dbo.report_sirea
  where OPERADORA = 'ALP' and GRUPO = 'OPERADORA' 
        and INICIO >= '20180801' and INICIO < '20180901'
)
SELECT count(*) as Total_Indisponibilidade_Inferior
  from Soma_Indisp
  where Somado < 366959808;
```